# Want to Access variable by its name with string value

Tags: vba

I want to get the value of a variable by constructing its name with two different strings.

To break it down to the minimum:

```
TA = 1
TB = 2
TC = 3
B = 2

Messagebox.Show(B*("T"+"B"))
```

I know this is minimal, and I don't want to use it in a complex code. I also know there are ways to do that, but I am working in an environment with minimal functions.

So is there an basic way to do this?

Comment: You can't do that. Consider using an array or a dictionary instead.

Comment: That are the ways I know. So It seems that there is no way without them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't reference a variable dynamically like that. It's against the law. Generally when folks start thinking this way the answer is "Use an Array". Instead, given your example, a dictionary would be best:

Example using a dictionary:

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add "TA", 1
dict.Add "TB", 2
dict.Add "TC", 3
b=2

MessageBox.Show(B*(dict("T" & "B")))
```

That `"T" & "B"` gets concatenated together to be `"TB"` and then it fetches the `value` at `key` `"TB"` in your dictionary `dict` which is `2` and does the math.

The `Dictionary` is good to learn because it's crazy powerful. You can store anything in a dictionary (including other dictionaries), not just numeric and string values.

Lastly, this example uses late-binding for the dictionary object which is nice, but you don't get code hints when you are writing your code and learning this from scratch without code hints is kind of garbagey.

Instead go to Tools>>References and check the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* box in the list. Then you can use your dictionary as if it were native:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary

dict.Add "TA", 1
....
```

---

As for a solution with an array. Generally folks are asking something like:

"Why doesn't this work?"

```
Dim var1, var2, var3, var4
var1="hi "
var2="there "
var3="what's "
var4="up."

For i=1 to 4
    output=output & (var & i)
Next

MsgBox(output)
```

Which is very similar to the question here. Instead of "Dynamic variable" we can use an array:

```
Dim arrayVar(1 to 4) As String
arrayVar(1)="hi "
arrayVar(2)="there "
arrayVar(3)="what's "
arrayVar(4)="up."

For i=1 to 4
    output=output & arrayVar(i)
Next

MsgBox(output)
```

Comment: "Generally when folks start thinking this way the answer is" - I was fully expecting "use PHP" there ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon omgno [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) The shame. THE HORROR!